# Decode values ignored in CGCreateImage

Tags: cocoa, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d, cgimage

I am creating a monochrome image with the following code:

```
  CGColorSpaceRef cgColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
  CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate (width, height, 1, 1, rowBytes, colorSpace, 0, dataProvider, decodeValues, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

where `decodeValues` is an array of 2 `CGFloat`'s, equal to `{0,1}`. This gives me a fine image, but apparently my data (which comes from a PDF image mask) is black-on-white instead of white-on-black. To invert the image, I tried to set the values of `decodeValues` to `{1,0}`, but this did not change anything at all. Actually, whatever nonsensical values I put into `decodeValues`, I get the same image.

Why is `decodeValues` ignored here? How do I invert black and white?

Comment: To invert black and white you just swap the decode values. And it definitely works. You need to post more of the real code, not just the function declaration and say 'it doesn't work'. Please don't take the wrong way - i'm interested to find out what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's some code for creating and drawing a mono image. It's the same as yours but with more context (and without necessary cleanup):

```
size_t width = 200;
size_t height = 200;
size_t bitsPerComponent = 1;
size_t componentsPerPixel = 1;
size_t bitsPerPixel = bitsPerComponent * componentsPerPixel;
size_t bytesPerRow = (width * bitsPerPixel + 7)/8;
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone;
CGFloat decode[] = {0.0, 1.0};
size_t dataLength = bytesPerRow * height;
UInt32 *bitmap = malloc( dataLength );
memset( bitmap, 255, dataLength );

CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData( NULL, bitmap, dataLength, NULL);

CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate (
                          width,
                          height,
                          bitsPerComponent,
                          bitsPerPixel,
                          bytesPerRow,
                          colorspace,
                          bitmapInfo,
                          dataProvider,
                          decode,
                          false,
                          kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                          );  

CGRect destRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
CGContextDrawImage( context, destRect, cgImage );
```

If i change the decode array to `CGFloat decode[] = {0.0, 0.0};` i always get a black image.
If you have tried that and it didn't have any effect (you say you get the same image whatever values you use), either: you aren't actually passing in those values but you think you are, or: somehow you aren't actually examining the output of CGImageCreate.